# Any case of std::promise that can't be replaced by a single thread running sequential produce-then-consume?

Tags: c++, promise

**Update 9th June 2020:**
Consolidating all the comments and answers here, and putting some more thought to this, I have created a flowchart below (click to zoom) to help decide when to use std::promise/future, and what are the trade-offs.
[image]

**Original post is as follows:**

I have been thinking about the real benefit of the `std::promise/future` mechanism. Examples almost everywhere tout this pattern - a single producer, single producer scenario where the producer notifies the consumer one-time that the resource in question is ready for consumption:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct StewableFood {
    int tenderness;
};

void slow_cook_for_12_hours(std::promise<StewableFood>& promise_of_stew) {
    std::cout << "\nChef: Starting to cook ...";

    // Cook till 100% tender
    StewableFood food{ 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
        food.tenderness = (i + 1) * 10;
        std::cout << "\nChef: Stewing ... " << food.tenderness << "%";
    }

    // Notify person waiting on the promise of stew that the promise has been fulfilled.
    promise_of_stew.set_value(food);
    std::cout << "\nChef: Stew is ready!";
}

void wait_to_eat_stew(std::future<StewableFood>& potenial_fulfilment_of_stew) {
    std::cout << "\nJoe: Waiting for stew ...";
    auto food = potenial_fulfilment_of_stew.get();
    std::cout << "\nJoe: I have been notified that stew is ready. Tenderness " << food.tenderness << "%! Eat!";
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<StewableFood> promise_of_stew;
    auto potenial_fulfilment_of_stew = promise_of_stew.get_future();

    std::thread async_cook(slow_cook_for_12_hours, std::ref(promise_of_stew));
    std::thread async_eat(wait_to_eat_stew, std::ref(potenial_fulfilment_of_stew));

    async_cook.join();
    async_eat.join();

    return 0;
}
```

To me, all this asynchronicity serves no purpose, because ultimately, the consumer's blocking wait on `future::get` makes this kind of usage equivalent to a single-threaded one with sequential produce-then-consume. I initially thought my example above is contrived. But if we look at the **one-time use only** constraint of a `std::promise/future` pair (i.e. you cannot re-write to the original promise nor re-read from the original future), it then follows that the above example becomes the only viable use case, since:

1. The set-once constraint means there can be only one producer, and
2. The get-once constraint means there can be only one consumer, and
3. Inferred from the above 2 set/get-once constraints, there shall be no looping that causes re-use on the same promise/future.

If the usage pattern in the above example is indeed the only viable use case, it then follows that there is no advantage in using `std::promise`, compared to doing just:

```cpp
void cook_stew_then_eat() {
    auto stew = slow_cook_for_12_hours();
    // wait 12 hours
    eat_stew(stew);
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(cook_stew_then_eat);
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Now, this conclusion seems suspicious. I am quite sure there is a good use case for `std::promise` which **cannot be replaced** by a single threaded sequential-produce-then-consume version which doesn't involve `std::promise`.

**Question: What is that use case(s)?**

**Note:** It is tempting to speculate that perhaps `std::promise/future` *somehow* allows us to asynchronously do something else without waiting on the fulfilment - might that be the advantage? Definitely not, because we can achieve the identical effect by putting that "something else" (e.g. some important work) in another thread. To illustrate:

```cpp
// cook and eat threads use std::promise/future
std::thread cook(...);
std::thread eat(...);

// Let's do important work on another thread
std::thread important_work(...);

cook.join();
eat.join();
important_work.join();
```

is identical to this solution that doesn't use `std::promise/future`:

```cpp
// sequentially cook then eat, NO NEED to use std::promise/future
std::thread cook_then_eat(...);

// Let's do important work on another thread
std::thread important_work(...);

cook_then_eat.join();
important_work.join();
```

Comment: What if Joe has to assemble and set the table before he can eat the stew? With 2 threads, he can do that while it's cooking. He couldn't if he was also the chef and had to monitor (stir??) it.

Comment: ...so, as I see it, the point of what you stand to gain from `promise`/`future` is if the eventual consumer isn't the producer and has their own work to do in the meantime. However, I'm keen to hear others' answers.

Comment: @underscore_d That can be achieved without std::promise too. In the latter sequential single-thread example, a separate thread can be run from main() to assemble the furniture. That's the problem actually - so far, I can't think of any use case where std::promise cannot be replaced by a counter-example which doesn't use it, and have the dual-threaded produce/consume replaced by sequential produce-consume. In fact, from my step-by-step analysis above, the read/write-once constraints of std::promise lead up to the inevitable conclusion that it is useless. I hope I am wrong.

Comment: Didactic examples are generally the simplest thing that demonstrates correct use of the interface.  You're looking for a _motivational example_, like, "this is the real situation that motivated us to use futures and promises" - but these are likely to be real code with lots of other complexity, and thus bad for teaching or demonstration.

Comment: @Useless I think the problem is not that the examples are didactic. Even without any code examples for reference, if we work backwards from the primary constraint that std::promise/future pairs are read/write-once only, then (as my above 3-step analysis shows) it follows that the only viable usage of std::promise/future is where: there is a single writer, a single blocked reader, no looping/re-use. There's no room for any other usage pattern, which is my understanding so far. It then follows that any example, whether didactic/motivational/in-production etc, has to conform to that pattern.

Comment: @Useless I am hoping you are right though. I am waiting for one code example to prove my conclusion wrong. There has to be some purpose for std::promise.

Comment: @underscore_d Thinking it through, I think your example can indeed highlight the superiority of std::promise vs produce-then-consume in a single thread. Let's complicate your example more, with the chef cleaning up after cooking. With std::promise, the consumer thread's code is Ikea-WaitOnFuture-Eat, producer thread is Cook-SetValue-Scrub. The equivalent non-std::promise version will be IkeaThread-Cook-RunDetachedScrubThread-JoinIkeaThread-Eat. Both are equivalent in concurrency. The std::promise version may have more overheads BUT its code is more expressive and has better decoupling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are actually correct, future/promise pattern can always be replaced with manual thread management (via thread joins, condition variables and mutexes) if you are careful about synchronization and object lifetimes.

The primary benefit of future/promise pattern is abstraction. It hides lifetime management and synchronization of the shared state from you, freeing you from the burden of doing it yourself.

Once the producer has a promise it doesn't need to know anything else about the consuming side, and likewise for the consumer and future. This makes it possible to write more concise, less error prone, and less coupled code.

Also keep in mind that as of C++20 `std::future` still lacks [continuations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future/then), which makes it a lot less powerful than it could be.

Answer (score 1):

> What is that use case(s)?

Any work that doesn't depend on the result of the promise can be done on other threads before waiting on the promise.

Let's extend your example to a stew competition

```
extern void slow_cook_for_12_hours(std::promise<StewableFood>& promise_of_stew);
extern Grade rate_stew(const StewableFood &);

std::map<Chef, Grade> judge_stew_competition(std::map<Chef, std::future<StewableFood>>& entries)
{
    std::map<Chef, Grade> results;
    for (auto & [chef, fut] : entries) { results[chef] = rate_stew(fut.get()); }
    return results;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<Chef, std::promise<StewableFood>> promises_of_stew = { ... };
    std::map<Chef, std::future<StewableFood>> fulfilment_of_stews;
    std::vector<std::thread> async_cook;
    for (auto & [chef, promise] : promises_of_stew)
    {
        fulfilment_of_stews[chef] = promise.get_future();
        async_cook.emplace(slow_cook_for_12_hours, std::ref(promise));
    }

    std::thread async_judge(judge_stew_competition, std::ref(fulfilment_of_stews));

    for (auto & thread : async_cook) { thread.join(); }
    async_judge.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If chefs didn't necessarily start simultaneously, and/or the stews can take different times to cook (depending on recipe?), the judge could start judging as soon as a new stew became available, rather than waiting for all chefs to finish. Not sure this helps your metaphorical example, but maybe it could be extrapolated to real code scenarios with similar patterns.

Comment: @underscore_d yes, those could all be appropriate

Comment: @Caleth The above example can be reduced to an identically performing one (in terms of concurrency) without using std::promise. The above example waits on each chef to finish before the judge grades the stew. Essentially, this reduces to a sequential produce-wait-consume which could have been accomplished without using std::promise: Simply launch multiple "cook_then_judge" threads where each thread does sequential cook-wait-judge. But, to illustrate my point, I will provide that counter example with code if I have time. All this stew talk's making me hungry.

Comment: @moog True, but I find it notable that `promise` adds value in terms of giving abstraction. Given this example, I find it easier to think about the threads as `n` for cooking and 1 for judging, rather than muddling up the roles of 'chef' and 'judge' into `cook_then_judge()`, which is really `chef_cooks_then_judge_judges()`.

Comment: E.g. if you `move`d the promises into the cook threads, it would be obvious there is no sharing of mutable state between the threads. `cook_then_judge` would need to co-ordinate populating `results`

Answer (score 1):

> Examples almost everywhere tout this pattern - a single producer, single producer scenario where the producer notifies the consumer one-time that the resource in question is ready for consumption.

May be that is not a good example.

Another example is a task that requires resources/datasets from different providers and there are only blocking calls available to fetch resources (or non-blocking calls cannot easily be integrated into one event loop in your application). In this case your consumer thread launches all resources requests as `std::async` and waits till they all complete in parallel, rather than sequentially. In this case it takes `max(times)` rather than `sum(times)` to fetch all the datasets, where `times` is an array of each provider response time.